# How to reproduce a MediaWiki element inside a Confluence Wiki

Tags: css, confluence

I have a MediWiki wiki that I am trying to migrate to Confluence. I have a specific element that I was not able to replicate in my Confluence Knowledge Base page.

It looks like this:

[image]

the code is this:

```
Set these compiler flags:   
{| style="font-style:regular; font-size:100%; width: 100%; border: 2px dashed; color: #000000; background-color: #FFF9E7;"
|-
|<code>$ export CC=clang </code>
|-
|<code>$ export CXX=clang </code>
|-
|<code>$ export FFLAGS=-ff2c </code>
|-
|}
```

How can I achieve this look inside a Confluence Macro Panel?

Answer (score 1):

Create a user macro which wraps the code macro for your formatting, then apply fresh styles based on the wrapper. Your user macro would look something like this

```
#@noparams
<style>.your-code pre { border: 1px dashed #ccc; background: yellow }</code>
<div class="your-code">$body</div>
```

Then simply wrap the Confluence code macro in your code wrapper macro.

Likely you'll have to change the style a little, but this should be a good start.